# Sending a key while other key is pressed doesn't spam the pressed key

Tags: autohotkey

Im trying to make a script to send a button while another one is pressed, like

```
$c::
    send {c down}
    sendQ()
    send {c up}
return
sendQ()
{
    if GetKeyState("c","P") {
        sendinput {q}
        sleep 2222
    }
}
```

it works, but not as intended.
It send cq with a 2222 interval like cq..cq..cq
I need the result like: cqcccccccqccccccccqcccc
is there a way to spam 'c' while pressing 'q' with interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
isCPressed := 0

c::
    Send c
    if (!isCPressed) { ; Avoid resetting the timer
        SetTimer, SendQ, 2222
    }
    isCPressed := 1
Return

c Up::
    SetTimer, SendQ, Delete
    isCPressed := 0
Return

SendQ() {
    SendInput q
}
```

In most situations, you can also replace

```
c::
    Send c
```

with

```
~c::
```

Answer (score 1):

Faking multi-threading in ahk can produce the required output. This way the script can send both c and q in their individual **threads**, after waiting for the specified time.

```
#Persistent

~c::
    Send, q ;~ for initial cq
    SetTimer, sendC, 100 ;~ frequency of sending c
    SetTimer, sendQ, 2222 ;~ frequency of sending q
return

;~ Sending c
sendC:
    Send, c
return

;~ Sending q
sendQ:
    Send, q
return
```

Comment: ty for reply, its not quite on key press but thanks for the idea. it spams c and sends q on c press